# TypeError : takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning Python. I have created a class that has a function, and in that function I have a dictionary. Note that I am checking whether a key exists in the dictionary or not, after which I  return a value from the function.

I am trying to access the function but when I try doing so, I get the following error: `"TypeError: first_func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"`

Below is the code which I am using :

```
class myFirst:
    def first_func():
        flag=0
        phonebook = {
            "A" : 938477566,
            "B" : 938377264,
            "C" : 947662781
        }
        # testing code
        if "A" in phonebook:
            flag=1
        if "D" not in phonebook:
            flag = 0
        return flag

myclassObj = myFirst()
status = myclassObj.first_func()

if status > 1:
    print ("Pass")
else:
    print ("fail")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

methods (functions or procedures belonging to a class) require a `self` argument , you may be familiar with `this` from other languages, (unless explicitly defined as a @staticmethod but it doesn't look like that's what you're going for here) like so:

```
class myFirst:
    def first_func(self): # here
        flag=0
        phonebook = {
            "A" : 938477566,
            "B" : 938377264,
            "C" : 947662781
        }
        # testing code
        if "A" in phonebook:
            flag=1
        if "D" not in phonebook:
            flag = 0
        return flag

myclassObj = myFirst()
status = myclassObj.first_func()

if status > 1:
    print ("Pass")
else:
    print ("fail")
```

it should work with that minor change.

if you want to use the `@staticmethod` decorator (in case the function doesn't actually require information from the class instance) you would do this instead:

```
class myFirst:
    @staticmethod #here
    def first_func():
```

you can find out more by checking the doc here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: thanks for explaining on this

Answer (score 2):

The error is you're not referencing self in your function signature.  Change the signature to

```
def first_func(self):
    # rest of code
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to adding the self argument, you could consider shortening your code as well. Your function returns a boolean value which you assigned to `status`, and then you compared status to an int. Instead, you can do something like this to save a few lines-

```
myClassObj = myFirst()
if myClassObj.first_func():
    print "Pass"
else
    print "Fail"
```

The complexity gain is quite minimal, but there's no reason to assign the boolean value to another variable when you can just use the value that's returned by your function.