# TypeError: takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python

Help me what am I making wrong here since am getting the below error,

TypeError: fizz_buzz() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

```
class FizzBuzz:
    def __init__(self, number_value):
        self.number_value = number_value

    def fizz_buzz():
        if number_value % 3 == 0 and number_value % 5 == 0:
            print("FizzBuzz")
        elif number_value % 3 == 0:
            print("Fizz")
        elif number_value % 5 == 0:
            print("Buzz")
        else:
            return f"{number_value} can't be multiplied by either 3 or 5"

number_value = int(input("Enter number: "))
fizzbuzz_object = FizzBuzz(number_value)
fizzbuzz_object.fizz_buzz()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError : takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269693/typeerror-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-1-was-given)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this means you should have all functions inside a class with atleast one argument,

```
def fizz_buzz(self):
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that when you are creating class methods you always have 1 argument called "self":

```
def fizz_buzz(self):
    if number_value % 3 == 0 and number_value % 5 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz")
    elif number_value % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")
    elif number_value % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")
    else:
        return f"{number_value} can't be multiplied by either 3 or 5"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to reference the current (self) instance of the class. Try:

```
def fizz_buzz(self):
```

Instead of:

```
def fizz_buzz():
```

Answer (score 3):

added the below code which fixed the issue:

```
`def fizz_buzz(self):`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed answer:

```
 fizzbuzz_object.fizz_buzz() # you did not pass the instance. "self" is just a symbol that represents the object
```

`fizz_buzz()` is a method. Methods are object type in Python. methods are callable like functions but they are bound some object and that object is injected to the method as its first parameter. That is why class methods are called "instance methods".if you run this:

```
   print(fizzbuzz_object.fizz_buzz)
```

you will get this:

```
    <bound method FizzBuzz.fizz_buzz of <__main__.FizzBuzz object at 0x7ffa306574f0>>
```

Python sees `.fizz_buzz` the dot and it knows that this method is bound to the object. this is when `fizz_buzz` turns to be a method. So far it was considered to be a function. This is actually difference between methods and functions. methods are bound.

```
type(FizzBuzz.fizz_buzz) is type(fizzbuzz_object.fizz_buzz)
```

this will return `false`. First type is "function", second type is "method"

```
If you called `FizzBuzz.fizz_buzz` like this you will not get same error.
```

Behind the scene this is what python calling

```
  FizzBuzz.fizz_buzz(fizzbuzz_object)
```

With injecting the object into the method, methods can access to the object's namespace. Also this passes 2 attributes to methods

```
print(fizzbuzz_object.fizz_buzz.__self__)
print(fizzbuzz_object.fizz_buzz.__func__)

<__main__.FizzBuzz object at 0x7ffa306574f0>  // object
<function FizzBuzz.fizz_buzz at 0x7ffa306620d0> // method
```

Answer (score 0):

**An instance method** needs `self` in the 1st argument as shown below:

```py
class Person:
            # Here     
    def test(self): 
        print("Test1")

obj = Person()
obj.test1()
```

Output:

```
Test1
```

In detail, I explain about **instance method** in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python/74482579#74482579) for [**What is an "instance method" in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python) and also explain about [**@classmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [**@staticmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python/74470227#74470227) for [**@classmethod vs @staticmethod in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python):