# 'task() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given' for python asyncio function

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

Within my python code, I am trying to design a piece of client code that connects to a WebSockets Server every second and then prints the timestamp and the obtained value from the server in a .csv file. This is given below:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import logging
import datetime
import time

starttime = time.time()  # start value for timed data acquisition

logger = logging.getLogger("websockets")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Switch to DEBUG for full error information
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())


class Timer:  # class for asynchronous (non-blocking) counter
    def __init__(self, interval, first_immediately, callback):
        self._interval = interval
        self._first_immediately = first_immediately
        self._callback = callback
        self._is_first_call = True
        self._ok = True
        self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())
        print("init timer done")

    async def _job(self):
        try:
            while self._ok:
                if not self._is_first_call or not self._first_immediately:
                    await asyncio.sleep(self._interval)
                await self._callback(self)
                self._is_first_call = False
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    def cancel(self):
        self._ok = False
        self._task.cancel()


async def test():
    async with websockets.connect(
        "ws://198.162.1.177:80/", ping_interval=None
    ) as websocket:

        await websocket.send(
            str(1.001)
        )  # send a message to the websocket server
        response = (
            await websocket.recv()
        )  # wait to get a response from the server
        print(response)
        dataline_pv1 = (
            datetime.datetime.today().isoformat()
            + ","
            + str(response)
            + ","
            + str(0)
            + "\n"
        )  # format and assemble data line
        file_name_pv1 = (
            "{:%Y%m%d}".format(datetime.datetime.today()) + "_flow.csv"
        )  # generate file name

        with open(
            file_name_pv1, "a"
        ) as etherm_file1:  # append dataline to file
            etherm_file1.write(dataline_pv1)


# asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever(test()) # run until test() is finished while True:
timer = Timer(interval=1, first_immediately=True, callback=test)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(test())
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    timer.cancel()
    pass
finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.close()
```

When this runs, I obtain the following message of my terminal (however the code does not crash):

```
test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I have seen from this question ([TypeError: takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461651/typeerror-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-1-was-given)) that this error occurs when a Class object is not defined properly, but my error seems to be occurring outside of a class framework. In addition, the desired .csv file is produced, however only one line is printed to the file, and does not repeat every second as desired.

What am I missing here? (also I am a complete novice with asyncio programming)

UPDATE: After changing the definition of `test()` to `async def test(timer=None)`, my code now runs as expected and outputs the values to a .csv file every second (roughly), but still throws up an error. Specifically:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<test() done, defined at flowmeterclient_v2.py:36> exception=ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Connect call failed ('198.162.1.177', 80)")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flowmeterclient_v2.py", line 37, in test
    async with websockets.connect("ws://198.162.1.177:80/", ping_interval=None) as websocket:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 604, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 622, in __await_impl__
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 798, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 785, in create_connection
    yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 439, in sock_connect
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 469, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('198.162.1.177', 80)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Timer` code passes the timer itself as the first argument in

```
await self._callback(self)
```

You may wish to change the signature of `test` to

```
async def test(timer=None):
```

so you can call it with or without the timer.

Comment: OK this now runs closer to what I would expect: however, I seem to now have an issue with the line  ```asyncio.ensure_future(test())```, which I would hope allows me to repeat the task() function. I have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really need the Timer here at all. Simply have an asyncio task that loops forever and has an `asyncio.sleep()` internally.

This also doesn't reconnect to the websocket server for each request, like your previous code did.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import logging
import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger("websockets")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Switch to DEBUG for full error information
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())


async def test():
    async with websockets.connect(
        "ws://198.162.1.177:80/",
        ping_interval=None,
    ) as websocket:
        while True:
            await websocket.send(str(1.001))
            response = await websocket.recv()
            print(response)
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            dataline_pv1 = f"{now.isoformat()},{response},0\n"
            file_name_pv1 = f"{now:%Y%m%d}_flow.csv"
    
            with open(file_name_pv1, "a") as etherm_file1:
                etherm_file1.write(dataline_pv1)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


asyncio.run(test())
```

Following up on comments, if you actually do need to reconnect for each request, you can refactor this like so:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import logging
import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger("websockets")
logger.setLevel(
    logging.INFO
)  # Switch to DEBUG for full error information
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())


async def get_data():
    async with websockets.connect(
        "ws://198.162.1.177:80/",
        ping_interval=None,
    ) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(str(1.001))
        response = await websocket.recv()
        return response


def save_data(response):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    dataline_pv1 = f"{now.isoformat()},{response},0\n"
    file_name_pv1 = f"{now:%Y%m%d}_flow.csv"

    with open(file_name_pv1, "a") as etherm_file1:
        etherm_file1.write(dataline_pv1)


async def test():
    while True:
        response = await get_data()
        save_data(response)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


asyncio.run(test())
```

Comment: Whilst this works, I have to reconnect each time as the websocket server sends the response whenever the client reconnects to the server. In the current configuration, all it does is sends the 1.001 string back as a response.

Comment: Well, in that case flip the while and with the other way around.

Comment: do you mean the ```async with``` or the ```with open```?

Comment: What about for python 3.5 and below? ```asyncio.run()``` only works for python 3.7 and above

Comment: Python 3.5 is EOL. You should look into upgrading. As noted in the docs, you can find the code for `asyncio.run()` in https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.9/Lib/asyncio/runners.py if you want to do the same in an older Python.